# Is "Mobile Reports" in SSRS 2016+ just a fancy way of saying "Modern reports for your mobile or web applications"?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

So my current understanding of SSRS 2016 is that it includes new modern-looking reports, but that these reports are only available in the Enterprise edition.  These modern reports are called "Mobile reports" in SSRS (see the screenshot link below), and that the Standard edition of SQL Server 2016+ only includes the older, non-modern-looking reports (charts, graphs) that the older versons of SSRS included.

[image: SSRS portal]

Is this correct that these modern reports ("Mobile reports") are only available with the Enterprise edition?  Also, even though these are "Mobile" reports, can I still use them effectively in a web application for PCs/laptops?

Comment: SSRS does not having styling of it's own. Mobile reports simply offer a mobile version with a less intrusive interface than the standard toolbar that you would see in a full desktop browser. The 'modern' design is down to the designer. You could easily reproduce the visualisations you show in your screen shot using SSRS from a standard edition.

Comment: Thanks Alan. How would I style my regular SSRS 2016 reports with the "modern" look offered with the Mobile reports?  Does Microsoft offer some different style sheets for reports?  I need an easy way to make the reports look more modern.

Comment: Hi, my point was that the report design is down to the designer. You can make a mobile report look really bad or a desktop report look really good but there are no themes or styles (even for mobile reports as far as I am aware). I was creating reports that looked like the KPI's shown back in 2008 for example.

Comment: You could copy the color scheme and sizing and just write an SSRS report "for" mobile without Enterpise. The one piece you cannot do as easily is show a kind of mini report at the report browsing level. Could be replicated with your own "dashboard" report though, I suppose.